# Error while update process

Tags: updates

Each time when I try to update Ubuntu by sudo apt-get update it fetches data from archive, but after reading package list I get this error:

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)

W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)

W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two lines in source configuration file of apt - and they saying that you're using two different architectures. Now you should:

1. check your arch
2. check configuration files of apt
3. comment out unnecessary line
4. run apt-get update again :)

Here's how:

1. check your arch
   In terminal/command line:

   uname -i

   On my ubuntu i've got this result: x86_64 - so i'm using amd64 if you've got other (in common) you're using i386
2. the configuration files for apt are in /etc/apt/ directory. This two problematique entries can be in /etc/apt/source.list or in /etc/apt/source.list.d/google-chrome.list
   you need to check it for yourself. Edit the right file with the command:

   gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
   or

   gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
   You need root privileges for it - so type your password
3. Comment out
   Now with # symbol you'll comment out unecessary line
4. Run apt-get update again

   sudo apt-get update